# WHERE column IS NOT '$value'?

Tags: sql, where-clause

I'm trying to select everything from the database except one thing.

Using the syntax in the title doesn't work, is their another way?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
WHERE column <> '$value'
```

Comment: Thank you, so simple. I'll check this answer in 12 minutes.

Comment: How could you combine this with a where column = value?

e.g. 

`SELECT * FROM $usertable WHERE Column IS NOT NULL AND Column <> 'Yes'`

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
WHERE column != '$value'
```

`IS NOT` is used with NULL

eg:

```
WHERE column IS NOT NULL
```